# Angular 2 - how do I data bind an SVG attribute to a component property?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular 2. For that, I'm trynig to create basic example.

I have a class with a variable that contains this string: `M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z`

I'm trying to use that string as a parameter for a svg element

Just to check:

This svg works:

```
<svg fill="white" height="64" width="64">
    <path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/>
</svg>
```

The variable `icon` in the template contains the correct string. I'm trying to do like this:

```
<svg fill="black" height="24" width="24">
  <path d={ icon } />
</svg>
```

And Adding `"` to the parameter `d`. But I cannot make it work

Comment: Interpolation is done with double curly braces {{classVariable}}

Comment: That works as text, but not as the parameter

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrong. From Mark's link to docs "interpolation and property binding can set only properties, not attributes" https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings) with SVG elements:

```
 <path [attr.d]="icon" />
```

Comment: I am just curious where can I find more on this? The documentation has only a quick reference in which a contradiction is present: the `attr.` is used and it is called not an attribute binding, but a property binding. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#svg-in-templates) is what I mean.